# Python: detectar tecla pulsada

Tags: python

Quiero detectar una tecla pulsada y lo he hecho con keyboard:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("q"):
        print("q")
```

Pero si hago eso imprime demasiadas veces q aunque le de un pequeño click por el `while`, hay una forma de hacerlo para que solo sea 1 vez?

Comment: Quizás deberías usar `kbd.on_press_key()`

Comment: @abulafia Hace unos minutos, hice una respuesta con esa solución. Pero luego probé mi respuesta (pues me olvide de probarla antes de publicarla) y me di cuenta de que si mantenés apretada la tecla, el callback se llama varias veces (menos que con el método del OP, pero aun así se llama varias veces)

Comment: Y el callback sigue llamandose por un rato incluso si soltaste la tecla...

Comment: @DanteS. Sí, pero ese ya es un problema de hardware. El propio teclado, cuando mantienes una tecla pulsada, genera varios eventos _keypress_, espaciados regularmente, como si pulsaras repetidas veces la tecla. Quizás el ritmo al que el teclado genera esos eventos es mayor que el ritmo al que puede procesarlos el programa, por lo que se acumulan en una cola y por eso sigue llamándose el callback después de soltarla. La única diferencia entre mantener una tecla pulsada o de verdad pulsarla repetidas veces, es que en el segundo caso habría también eventos _keyrelease_ y en el primero no.

Comment: Quizás se podría jugar entonces con registrar callbacks para eventos _keypress_ y _keyrelease_, para así poder diferenciar entre verdaderas pulsaciones repetidas o una tecla que se ha dejado pulsada.

Comment: @abulafia Eso estaba pensando. Dejo en tus manos esta pregunta? Eres mejor que yo explicando. Y en pensar este tipo de cosas al parecer.

Comment: Hmm... la verdad que la biblioteca keyboard no me parece muy apropiada. En linux por ejemplo requiere permisos de admin para ejecutarse . Y puede hacer cosas "raras" como keyloggers, o insertar comandos en el teclado. Y parece que no funciona si no estás en la consola (es decir, si estás por ejemplo en una sesión remota vía ssh). Quizás merezca la pena investigar en otras alternativas

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres que se imprima una sola vez, puedes romper el ciclo:

```
import keyboard as kb
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("q"):
        print("q")
        break
```

O llevar una variable de control:

```
import keyboard as kb
impreso = Falso
while True:
    if kb.is_pressed("q") and not impreso:
        print("q")
        impreso = True
```

#Advertencia: He escrito el código en el propio navegador, no hay garantía de que no tenga uno o dos errores sintácticos, pero la idea es que captes la idea.

Comment: quiero que funcione como un macros, si se rompe el ciclo ya no funciona, quiero que le doy una vez y se imprima una vez, y le doy otra y otra, como si escribiera "a" si le doy a la tecla "a" escribo "a" una vez

Comment: Bueno, yo escribí una respuesta para la pregunta que escribiste, no para lo que pueda estar en tu mente fuera de lo que está escrito. Dale una mirada a [ask], ordena tus ideas, escribe una nueva pregunta y asegurate de incluir la información necesaria para que quién no está dentro de ti, entienda lo que buscas y cual es el problema para lograrlo.

Comment: ```
import keyboard as kb
import time
import pyautogui as pau

xd = True
while xd:
    if kb.is_pressed("q"):
        pau.typewrite("XD")
        xd = False
        time.sleep(0.1)
        xd = True
```

Comment: algo asi queria, perdon por el desorden pero no se como poner codigo en comentarios

Comment: Los comentarios no son para publicar código, más que ocasionalmente si es un fragmento de una línea o menos, algo muy sencillo. Por eso mi sugerencia es **que hagas una nueva pregunta**. NO sugiero siquiera editar esta, que en mi opinión, ya ha sido respondida satisfactoriamente.